# how to open a canvas in another window then draw somthing on it in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, window

I want to click a button to open another window with a canvas in it, then I can draw some image on it. How can I do that? The following codes gives [object HTMLCanvasElement], but nothing shows there. It should be an image drawing on it already.

```
 var currentcanvas = document.getElementById(theCanvas);
 var popup = window.open("");
 popup.document.write(currentcanvas);
```

The following code shows the right image, but I cannot use Canvas2Image to convert the canvas to image then showing in the new window, since I need to draw some stuff on it.

```
 var renderedImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(theCanvas, true, width, height, "");
 var dataURL = renderedImg.src;
 var popup = window.open("");
 popup.document.write('<img src="' + dataURL + '" />');
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Share the code for what you have done? Then it would be easier to improve/modify/add something in your code => question will be better regarded/answered by viewers.

Comment: Maybe with trials and errors you get closer to the desired result. Try to take with small steps, reconstruct the whole idea into small chunks and definitely you'll be much more successful.

Comment: thanks guys! I've solved with this issue, and forgot to add comment here. Your advice are really useful! thanks again.